# jQuery: contains() works in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, contains

I've got an ajax function that gets some values based on the selected value in a dropdown. I'm trying to enable/disable some fields based on a substring. I found 'contains' to work in firefox, but testing in chrome and safari tells me that the object 'has no method contains'

```
if ($d.attr("embed").contains('$var_2$')) { 
    //do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Is there an alternative to contains that will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

what you're using there is [`String.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains), not [`jQuery.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/). this is because you're using the function on `.attr`s return-value, wich is a String, not a jQuery-Object.

to use `jQuery.contains()` (wich works cross-browser), you could do this instead:

```
$d.contains('$var_2$')
```

but note that this won't only search in the specified attribute but the whole element instead.

so what you most likely want to do is using [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (wich also works cross-browser):

```
$d.attr("embed").indexOf('$var_2$') != -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, that worked! I had seen indexOf suggested as an alternative and tried it but my syntax must have been off because I was not getting the desired results. Works perfectly wth your given syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a update to this answer: Mozilla devs decided to rename that method to `includes` in Firefox 48 for ES 6 and compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf`, it should work in all browsers.

```
if ($d.attr("embed").indexOf('$var_2$') > -1) { 
    //do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of contains.